# System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Not a valid file name

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, oledb

If you visit:

http://www.acoin.co.il/

you will see the error/message:

**Source Error:**

```
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
```

**Stack Trace:**

```
[OleDbException (0x80004005): Not a valid file name.]
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString constr, OleDbConnection connection) +351
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject) +86
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup) +31
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) +76
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +126
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open() +43
   Acoin.index.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +145
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +91
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +74
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2207
```

This is my code;

```
string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=http://www.acoin.co.il/database1.mdb;Persist Security Info=False";
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
conn.Open();
```

Comment: You cannot use http protocol in this kind of connection string. File has to be either local or on the LAN. Since it's seem to be the same as code location try `Data Source=database1.mdb` OR use location relative to code location

Answer (score 0):

Seems like that URL is broken (unrelated to the OleDB connection):

http://www.acoin.co.il/database1.mdb:

> 404 - File or directory not found. 
>  The resource you are looking for
>   might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily
>   unavailable.

However I'd be surprised if you could use an HTTP URL as a database file location